# Flex: Change text value with loop and make image from every changed value?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to change taxt value from loop and every time I have changed it I take image from that.

I have two numeric steppers where other is start number and other is end number. I have also button that starts function.

So after pressed it starts:

```
private function makeFrames():void
{

    for (var i:int = 0; i < endFrameNumber.value; i++) 
    {
        currentFrameNumber++;
        frameText.text = currentFrameNumber.toString();
        makeImage(currentFrameNumber);
    }

}
```

Then I make image from text:

```
private function makeImage(value:int):void
{
    var projectFolderName:String = createFolder();

    bitmapData = new BitmapData(frameText.width,frameText.height, true, 0x00ffffff);
    bitmapData.draw(frameText,new Matrix());
    var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    var png:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var ba:ByteArray = png.encode(bitmapData);
    newImage = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(projectFolderName + "/" + "frame-number_" + value + ".png");
    fileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(newImage, FileMode.APPEND);
    fileStream.writeBytes(ba);
    fileStream.close();

}
```

So first I change text value and then I try to capture it. It make images yes, but all numbers is same. So how I can make it to change text value every time when I run "makeImage" in loop and it captures all images between start and end numbers??

Using Flash Builder 4.6 and AIR.

Comment: If you `trace(value);` in makeImage, you get different values right ? (If not there's something wrong with `currentFrameNumber `). If you do get different images (with proper names) but with the same number displayed inside the image, I imagine the component hasn't finished updating. I haven't used flex in a while, but can you try to call `frameText.validateNow();` after setting the text and before calling `makeImage` ? Basically, try to force the component to update, rather than wait for it's default lifecycle updates.

Comment: Thanks @George ! It works with that `frameText.validateNow();` You saved my day, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about [Flex Components Lifecycle](http://www.slideshare.net/mrinalwadhwa/custom-components-in-flex-4).

So, there are two way to solve your problem:

1. Using invalidateProperties -> commitProperties.
2. addEventListener on Event.ENTER_FRAME

Sure you can't use `foreach`. In each enter frame you should:

1. Set new text
2. Invalidate text display
3. Make and save image